# popping and dismissing viewControllers till root when remote notification is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, uitabbarcontroller

My app use a `UITabBarViewController` and a `UINavigationController`. I saw in some application like Line for example:

[image]

When you are on the profile screen and a push notification for a new message is coming, if you tap this notification, you will be redirected to the chat screen and they reset the last tabBar item to it's root (so pop and dismiss for this case)

Currently, in my AppDelegate.swift I have implemented `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)` with:

```
let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
var rootTabBarController: ENTabBarController!

case .visitor: 
    print("visitor notification received")              
    if rootViewController is ENTabBarController {
        rootTabBarController = rootViewController as! ENTabBarController
        rootTabBarController.selectedIndex = 2
    } else {
        rootTabBarController = ENTabBarController()
        rootTabBarController.selectedIndex = 2
        window?.rootViewController = rootTabBarController
    }
```

My problem here is if I was in another view in my app that have been pushed or presented, when I will tap on the UITabBarController it will redirect me to the pushed or presented view and not to the root.

Answer (score 0):

All you need here is...

**Step 1:**

Set your `UITabBarController` as the `rootViewController` of a `UINavigationController` and set your `UINavigationController` as the `rootViewController` of your application window.

**Step 2:**

Always `Push` or `Present` your controllers using `UINavigationController` instead of `UITabBarController`

**Step 3:**

When your relevant method is triggered, write your code like this:

```
let navigationVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as! UINavigationViewController

navigationVC.popToRootViewController(true/false);

let tabVC = navigationVC.rootViewController as! YourTabViewController

tabVC.selectedIndex = 2 //or your desired index.
```